# nopCommerce multistore enable/disable functionaliity not working when radio button with different id's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 3.40

I am using multistore functionality in my nopCommerce plugin. and I have some issue on multistore default script.

```
<tr class="method">
        <td class="adminTitle">
            @Html.OverrideStoreCheckboxFor(model => model.Method_OverrideForStore, model => model.Method, Model.ActiveStoreScopeConfiguration)
            @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Method):
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Method, 1, new { id = "one" })
                    <label for="one">one</label><br/>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Method, 2, new { id = "two" })
                    <label for="two">two</label><br />
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Method, 3, new { id = "three" })
            <label for="three">three</label>
        </td>
</tr>
```

When I use `@Html.OverrideStoreCheckboxFor()` for multistore functionality and make field name in checkbox.

html generated:

```
<input id="Method_OverrideForStore" class="multi-store-override-option" 
       type="checkbox" value="true" 
       onclick="checkOverridenStoreValue(this, '#Method')" 
       name="Method_OverrideForStore" data-for-input-selector="#Method">
```

and my radio button id like "one", "two", "three" and this html generated find "Method" id in radio button but not finding id so, multistore enable/disable feature is not working.

Thanks in advance,

Ragards,
Jatin